# saving as pdf and EPS in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, eps

I'm trying to save artboards as PDF and EPS.  I have the latest version of illustrator. When I got to export > save as ... I don't see these options.

Here's the options https://prnt.sc/g0mst6

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Eps and pdf are native formats yo do not export them just save.

Comment: Yes, what joojaa said… try Save As… rather than Export.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "export". Use "Save as" or "Save a Copy". 
[image]